# Rename directory during copy using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using gradle to build an android application. I'm copying several files and folders to the assets folder. I have now run into the problem, that some of the files may have a too long filename, as do have folders (aapt cannot handle filenames longer than 100 characters).

Therefore I'm renaming the files during the copy operation like this:

```
    copy {
     from('A')
     into('B')
     rename ('too-long-filename', 'shorter-filename')
     rename ('too-long-directoryname', 'shorter-directoryname')
    }
```

However, this works fine for files but fails for directories. Is there a special command to achieve rename during copy using gradle?

The error says:

Error Code:
        1
 Output:
  /home/curiosity/AndroidStudioProjects/App/build/..way too long directory names../: error: Invalid directory name, unable to add.

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that. The error always is:

"Unable to add directory. Invalid directory name." 

I understand this because the android packaging tool indeed does not allow names longer than 100 characters. Renaming helps for the file but has no effect for the directory. The error is the same with or without the line:

rename ('too-long-directoryname', 'shorter-directoryname')

Comment: Post error in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the FileTree visit but you you have to save the directories, can't change those while you are traversing.  And if you just want to shorten the name, probably can use the groovy substring notation longname[0..-10]

Something like:

```
def dirs = []
fileTree("./longdirectoryname").visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
    if (!details.isDirectory()) {
        // rename
    } else {
        dirs.add(details.file)
    }
}

dirs.each { // rename directories here }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a solution I can live with :) Nevertheless, I tend to add some preprocessing and short too long filenames as well as adapting all references.